# List of books which teaches historical Aristotelian logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, history-of-philosophy, aristotle

**Background**: I want to study philosophy and I think a good way is to first learn logic, so I tried reading The Categories. But even after trying so hard, I didn't understand it. The writing is very obscure, not enough examples and Aristotle changes his topic faster than the speed of light. So I thought I should read commentaries on Categories, I chose [Simplicius'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicius_of_Cilicia) commentary, and I didn't understand most of it.

**Question**: What references are available to teach Aristotelian logic in its historical form?

**Clarification**: So I would like a list of references that teach Aristotelian logic. *Please note I don't want to learn formal logic, and I am not asking for commentaries on Aristotelian logic; I already have many.* The book I am asking for should teach Aristotelian logic specifically; all or most of the **topics mentioned in *The Organon*** and the contents of the book must overlap strongly with the Organon.

**Examples** of such books are Ockham's [*Summa Logicae*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_Logic) and [*Logica Or Summa Lamberti*](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Logica_Or_Summa_Lamberti.html?id=LSjcrQEACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y).

Comment: To teach Aristotelian logic? Per se A's logic is mainly syllogism and you can find it in most introductory books on logic, like e.g. Copi's symbolic logic. If instead you are searching for a modern study of original A's logic, you can see e.g. J.Corcoran (editor), [Ancient Logic and Its Modern Interpretations](https://books.google.it/books?id=TBorBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) and G.Patzig, [Aristotle’s Theory of the Syllogism](https://books.google.it/books?id=8g3wCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) and J.Lear, [Aristotle and Logical Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=lXI7AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA41)

Comment: Regarding *Categories*, maybe useful: Michael Griffin, [WHAT DOES ARISTOTLE CATEGORIZE : SEMANTICS AND THE EARLY PERIPATETIC READING OF THE CATEGORIES (2012)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44254100?seq=1) as well as Leila Haaparanta (editor), [Categories of Being](https://books.google.it/books?id=bUppAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1)

Comment: And why not using a general introduction, like e.g. [The Oxford Handbook of Aristotle](https://books.google.it/books?id=vTVsrl0mnH4C&pg=PR7) ?

Comment: @Mauro_ALLEGRANZA Do you know ancient books used as an alternative or guide to Aristotelian logic? Like Ockhams book, Porphyry’s
Isagoge(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isagoge).

Comment: The Stanford Encyclopedia has a concise introduction. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/
A A Luce's 1958 book, Teach Yourself Logic, is a longer introduction. Honestly though, Aristotle's logic is mainly of historical interest and is of limited use in studying philosophy. It is typically taught in Catholic institutions where they have a particular take on the connection between logic and theology.

Comment: @Bumble '...and is of limited use in studying philosophy' Why? Philosophy and science are logical subjects, they have demonstrations, axioms .....  How can one learn them if he doesn't know to argue(logically)? Doesn't that makes A's logic important.

Comment: It makes logic important, but A's logic is mainly only a matter of historical interest. It is antiquated and was superceded over 120 years ago. Our knowledge of logic has advanced leaps and bounds in the last 120 years, and arguably throwing off the shackles of aristotelian thinking has helped make that possible.

Comment: All logic texts before 1845 dealt with Aristotelian logic my friend. There was no such thing as "Mathematical logic" existing which Bumble mentioned above.  Some authors do cover Aristotelian logic extremely well in philosophy: Irving Copi & Marc Cohen have a famous textbook; so does Patrick Hurley. Both of those textbooks were written by philosophers--not mathematicians. Modern logic is Mathematical logic which has a different purpose than Aristotle's logic so this debate will go on forever. All logic is formal by definition. Don't take labels LITERALLY. All of logic goes by past patterns.

Comment: Like [Miller, The Structure of Aristotelian Logic](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Structure_of_Aristotelian_Logic/P8JgCgAAQBAJ), [Spangler, Logic: An Aristotelian Approach](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Logic/OaFNAwAAQBAJ) or [Parry-Hacker, Aristotelian Logic](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Aristotelian_Logic/rJceFowdGEAC)?

Comment: An Analysis Of Aristotle's Logic , by the Scottish philosopher Thomas Reid : https://archive.org/details/analysisaristot00reidgoog/page/n18/mode/1up

Comment: A very useful edition of the Organon (with notes and commentaries) https://archive.org/details/organonorlogical02arisuoft/page/16/mode/1up

Comment: Edited in response to multiple closure votes.

Comment: seems like a reasonable question, why the downvotes?

Comment: @J_D Thank you for editing the question.